# Angular UI Bootstrap - Cannot delete popover when triggering element is removed from DOM

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, popover, destroy

I am using a javascript library that will add/remove elements to the DOM when some data is updated.
To add a new element to the DOM it calls a template function returning an element. In my case, the template function is defined inside an angular directive and returns something like `return $compile(html)(scope)[0];` because I need to use the UI Bootstrap Popover directive inside the added element.
For the Popover, I need to use `popover-append-to-body="true"`.

My problem is, if the triggering element is removed from the DOM, the popover is never removed. So if we add a new triggering element, a second popover will be appended to body, etc.

Here is a simplified example : http://plnkr.co/edit/AFsXBcaLBAs0F2garbAu?p=preview
Clicking on the "Click" button opens the popover, clicking "Remove" removes the "Click" button, clicking "Add" re-adds the "Click" button and clicking "Click" again adds a second popover to the DOM.

**How can I remove the Popover directive when the triggering element is removed from the DOM ?**
I need to totally deletes it, not only hide it/remove it from the DOM (I can hide it with `popover-is-open` but when this is set back to true, I see the popover still exists).
Is there a way to call destroy on the Popover directive of the element that will be deleted ?

Comment: don't do DOM manipulation in the controller, you may want to redesign your code

Comment: @svarog This was just a quick example to show the popover problem. In my actual code I am not doing DOM manipulation in the controller but I am using a (not angular) library (that I call from inside an angular directive by the way). The problem is the "buttons" are created and added to the DOM by this library so I cannot keep their state in an array. What I wrote as vanilla js in my example is what I cannot control with angular in my real application.

Comment: then you have an entirely different problem. you'll need to import that button generating code to a link function inside a directive and keep a `$watch` on it, and `$apply` for changes

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do DOM manipulation in you a controller, both in JS and HTML, that's why directives are for, and for your case there were a couple of built in directives you could have used.

1. you should have kept an array to represent your buttons and popover states
2. you should place all you JS code in your controller, and used `ng-click` to bind click events to functions in your controller
3. don't use `onclick` when you have `ng-click`
4. The angular API works completely different then vanilla JS and even jquery, so don't mix them, use what Angular provides you, refer to the docs for help.

[Here is your "revamped" code](http://plnkr.co/edit/sNbtXcUY4FbWgnOaiAR7?p=preview)